# Unexpected conflicting implementation for TryFrom

Tags: rust, type-conversion

I want to implement the trait `TryFrom` in a case like this:

```rust
struct T1;
struct T2(T1);

impl<U> TryFrom<U> for T2 where U: Into<T1> {
    type Error = ();
    fn try_from(val:U) -> Result<T2, Self::Error> {
        unimplemented!();
    }
}
```

which gives me this error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::TryFrom<_>` for type `T2`
 --> src/lib.rs:4:1
  |
4 | impl<U> TryFrom<U> for T2 where U: Into<T1> {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
          - impl<T, U> TryFrom<U> for T
            where U: Into<T>;
```

Here `U` implement `Into<T1>` not `Into<T2>` thus I don't really understand the error. I tried to confirm there is no blanket implementation by implementing this and it compiles without conflict:

```rust
struct T1;
struct T2(T1);

impl Into<T2> for T1 {
    fn into(self) -> T2 {
        unimplemented!();
    }
}
```

Is there any way around it? I don't want a default implementation here.

Comment: Incidentally, this has nothing to do with your problem, but the `Error` type could be a void type, rather than a ZST.

Comment: This is sadly a known issue with `TryFrom`. Because Rust can't know whether your `U` implements both `Into<T1>` _and_ `Into<T2>` it can't allow this because it would conflict with the blanket implementation. [This](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/50133#issuecomment-646908391) seems to be the best(?) workaround I could find. [Specialization]() should hopefully make this easier.

Comment: @BlackBeans I've never heard "void type" in relation to Rust before. What's that? `Never`?

Comment: @isaactfa Void types in Rust are types for which there is no value of such type. `!` (to be read *never*) and `Infallible` are two such types defined in the standard library / in Rust's core (the latter being only useful because the former can't be used in stable Rust yet), but really that just means `enum Void {}`. They are useful to encode in the type system that such a value cannot be built. In this case, a `Result<T, !>` would mean that it can only ever be an `Ok(...)`, because `Err(x)` would mean `x: !`, which is impossible.

Comment: Also, every void type is isomorphic. If I have `Void1` and `Void2` as defined above, then `|x| match x {}` is the isomorphism (this will in particular produce a type `!` out of any void type, which is useful).

Comment: @BlackBeans Okay, I know all about `never`, I'd just never hear "void type" before.

Comment: @isaactfa Thanks so I suppose this would work only if we would have a way to forbid the conflicting implementation like `where U: !Into<T2>`

Comment: @BlackBeans who calls it a "void type"? I've not heard anyone refer to it as such and googling doesn't help out either. Sounds especially confusing since void has a different meaning in other languages.

Comment: @kmdreko I don't remember *everywhere* I've seen this terminology, but one that I recall is the Rustonomicon, where they're also called empty types. See [the section about empty types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/exotic-sizes.html#empty-types).

Comment: An other reference I just recalled is Haskell's [Void type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/void-0.7/docs/Data-Void.html), which is the same as Rust's `!`.

Answer (score 1):

Trait implementations are not allowed to conflict. A type is perfectly allowed to implement both `Into<T1>` and `Into<T2>`. Your implementation would cause an ambiguity in this case whether to use the `T: TryFrom<U>` implementation by the built-in blanket implementation or from your blanket implementation. And thus there is a conflict and the compiler rejects your implementation.

Essentially **you cannot implement `TryFrom` generically** because of the blanket implementation; you can't avoid a potential conflict.

Your confirmation doesn't mean anything since there is no such blanket implementation for `Into` that would conflict between `T1` and `T2`. If you tried to implement it *generically*, like `impl Into<T2> for U where U: Into<T1>`, that'd be a problem as well. The genericism is the core problem.